# How do I display values in an multi-dimensional array from database while keeping values unique?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I display all values from this dimensional array from a database and not show repeated values?

Below is an example code.

```
$darray = Array
(
Array ( [0] => apple, [1] => pear, [2] => appetiser )

Array ( [0] => apple, [1] => pear, [2] => appetiser )

Array ( [0] => indian, [1] => vegetarian, [2] => entree )

Array ( [0] => german, [1] => snack, [2] => vegetarian ) 

Array ( [0] => mexican, [1] => soup, [2] => pear )

Array ( [0] => apple, [1] => snack )

Array ( [0] => italian, [1] => entree, [2] => pear, [3] => vegetarian )
)
```

Comment: You could create an associative array  which will only hold unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your multidimensional array, collect the values and use [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique) to extract unique values:

```
<?php

$darray = array
(
    array('apple', 'pear', 'appetiser'),
    array('apple', 'pear', 'appetiser'),
    array('indian', 'vegetarian', 'entree',),
    array('german', 'snack', 'vegetarian') ,
    array('mexican', 'soup', 'pear'),
    array('apple', 'snack'),
    array('italian', 'entree', 'pear', 'vegetarian'),
);

$array = array();

foreach ($darray as $monodimensional_array)
{
    foreach ($monodimensional_array as $value)
    {
        $array[] = $value;
    }
}

$array = array_unique($array);
```

Comment: 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' error was received.

Comment: @NicholasWong try adding this (array) in the foreach like foreach ((array) $darray as $monodimensional_array) on Benoit code

Comment: that would only display 1 array.. I would like to display all arrays and then make it unique.

Comment: @NicholasWong Well, I doesn't have any error... I've added sample data from your question to clarify what `$darray` is.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a intermediate storage array to store values that you have already printed and query that to make sure you are printing only unique array values.

```
<?php
$darray = array
(
    array ( 0 => 'apple', 1 => 'pear', 2 => 'appetiser' ),
    array ( 0 => 'apple', 1 => 'pear', 2 => 'appetiser' ),
    array ( 0 => 'indian', 1 => 'vegetarian', 2 => 'entree' ),
    array ( 0 => 'german', 1 => 'snack', 2 => 'vegetarian' ) ,
    array ( 0 => 'mexican', 1 => 'soup', 2 => 'pear' ),
    array ( 0 => 'apple', 1 => 'snack' ),
    array ( 0 => 'italian', 1 => 'entree', 2 => 'pear', 3 => 'vegetarian' )
);

$printedArray = array();
foreach($darray as $darr)
{
    foreach($darr as $val)
    {
        if(!in_array($val,$printedArray))
        {
            echo $val."<br>"; 
            //you could alternately store the value into an array[] here
            //and print it later...
            array_push($printedArray,$val);
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

This should print:

```
apple
pear
appetiser
indian
vegetarian
entree
german
snack
mexican
soup
italian
```